# Need a windows batch script that will zip files by name AND date

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am in the process of editing a little script utility on Windows 2012 that will recursively go through a directory, look at each file and zip it up based in it's age (over 30 days) but ignore any files with the .zip extension.

I can get the script to do either zip files by age or ignore the .zip extension but not both.

Here is the script I am working with

```
forfiles /P G:\temp\admin\archives /s /m *.* /D -365 /C "cmd /c for /r %f in (*.*) do if not %~xf==.zip C:\progra~1\7-Zip\7z a -sdel %f.zip %f"
```

Feedback appreciated.

Comment: Then why are you using `-365` for the days?  I am not understanding why you are using the `FOR /R`?  `FORFILES` is already enumerating the directory tree for you. `FORFILES` has a variable for the extension of the files it has found.  Why aren't you using that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```bat
forfiles /P G:\temp\admin\archives /s /m *.* /D -30 /C "cmd /c if not @ext=="zip" C:\progra~1\7-Zip\7z a -sdel @fname.zip @path"
```

Comment: If I were you I would test that code again and revise it.

Comment: The @EXT variable also does not have a period in it. FORFILES is also using the /S switch so you will need to use the full path to the file name for 7zip to know which file to compress. Using quotes directly within the /C option will not work. Anything you need to quote inside the surrrounding quotes must be written in hex. 0x22